# Cheapest phone which can plug and play into ubuntu for tethering?

Tags: phone, tethering

Can someone please show me a very very very cheap phone which I can plug into my laptop which uses Ubuntu 10.04 so I can use the phone as a modem, i.e. tethering the data allowance on my contract.

The phone must be very cheap
It must simply be plug and play, no configuring
It must be unlocked, or free to unlock or cost less than £60 including the cost to unlock it

I understand that android 2.2 phones fit the above requirements except the 3rd requirement afaik.  The cheapest android phone I have found is about £60, but costs about £30 to unlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few options I can think of:

1 - Get a 3G dongle instead.  There is a monthly cost associated, but it is a device for this very purpose.  You will need to look at the compatibility of specific dongles with Ubuntu.

2 - Check ebay for 2nd hand phones, it is possible that you find cheap Android phones there.